# Is there a shorthand for `if Array.find`?

Tags: javascript

I want to do the equivilent of this:

```js
const arr = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}]; 

const item = arr.find(v => v.id===2); 

if (item) {
   console.log(item); 
}
```

Is there a shorthand expression I can do where I can both evaluate whether an item was found, and use that item inside the block?

Something like:

```
if (const item = arr.find(v => v.id ===2) {
    console.log(item); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, just a simple tweak to your code - change `item` to a `let` declared *outside* if the `if` so that it can be reassigned in the condition:

```js
const arr = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}];
// not actually necessary, but leaving it out will implicitly assign to global object:
let item;
if (item = arr.find(v => v.id ===2)) {
    console.log(item); 
}
```

That said, I wouldn't recommend it - assigning to variables inside a conditional is a code smell. I prefer your original version where the `.find` is done outside.

You could also make your own function for something like this, if you wanted. The function definition isn't tiny, but now you'll be able to *call* it concisely:

```js
function findAnd(arr, condition, callback) {
  const item = arr.find(condition);
  if (item) callback(item);
}

const arr = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}];
findAnd(arr, v => v.id === 2, item => console.log(item));
```

Comment: That's not really _short_ hand. It's longer than the original solution.

Comment: This is not longer; it has the same tokens as the original (except that it switches `let` for `const`); they're just arranged differently.  The difference here is that you can save the `let item;` statement, if it can be defined elsewhere.  It's not really much of a savings, but I think we're all grasping at straws here.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting... while the original isn't really long it was kinda fun to poke around. Not super short but something.

```
for (let item = arr.find(v => v.id === 2);item;) {
    console.log('Found', item); 
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just care to use `item` inside your `if` block, you don't need `var`, `let` or `const`. But, the drawback is that the variable will be bound globally.

```js
const arr = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}]; 

if (item = arr.find(v => v.id === 2)) {
   console.log(item);
}
```